# how to remove espaces white in @foreach ( $produtos as $produto )

Tags: php, html, css, laravel

At this moment i created a pagination using the @foreach ( $produtos as $produto ) in laravel and it has white spaces because of the product name, is there any simple way to solve this?
[image]

Comment: Please go read [ask] and [mre]. Just showing a picture of the output, is not an appropriate way to ask here on this site, not by far.

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. What white space? The different sized boxes? The placement of the last box? You should provide a more detailed description and some code to clarify what you need help with.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow @Micael Pereira. Please consider reading this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

You'll probably want to truncate your product names so they don't get too long, or specify a minimal/fixed height in CSS for your products so they don't push the second line to the back. Consider utilizing a grid, such as the one included in Bootstrap and Semantic UI.